# Thread overflowing his stack Rust

Tags: rust, webserver, project, stack-overflow

I'm doing a small project that requires a simple HTTP server running in order to work. As I'm learning Rust, I try to do it the hard way and not use higher level crates.
So basically, as seen in the following screenshot, I can easily get the server to answer with the index.html file, but when I ask the favicon.ico, I get a Stack Overflow.
[image: Problem showcase]
Here is my function that handles the TcpStream:

```
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(&mut stream);
    let http_request: Vec<String> = buf_reader
        .lines()
        .map(|result| result.unwrap())
        .take_while(|line| !line.is_empty())
        .collect();
    println!("Request: {:#?}", http_request);
    let mut first_line = http_request[0].split_whitespace();
    // Get the method
    let method = first_line.next().unwrap();
    // Get the path
    let path = first_line.next().unwrap();
    match (method, path) {
        ("GET", _) => {
            // sanitize the choice
            let illegal_choices = &["../", "etc", "home", "root", "var", "id_rsa"];
            let mut choice = path;
            for illegal_choice in illegal_choices {
                if choice.contains(illegal_choice) {
                    choice = "/404.html"; // redirect to not found
                    break;
                } 
            }
            if choice == "/" {
                choice = "/index.html";
            }  
            // try to find the file
            let file = std::fs::File::open(format!(".{}", choice));
            let mut page: File;
            if file.is_err() {
                page = File::open("./404.html").unwrap(); // if the file is not found, return the 404 page
            } else {
                page = file.unwrap();
            }
            // header for an image file
            let headers_img = [
                "HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
                "Content-type: image/jpeg",
                "Transfer-Encoding: chunked",
                "\r\n"
            ];
            let mut encoded = Vec::new();
            let mut buf = Vec::new();
            page.read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
            {
                let mut encoder = Encoder::with_chunks_size(&mut encoded, 8);
                encoder.write_all(&buf).unwrap();
            }
            let mut response = headers_img.join("\r\n")
                .to_string()
                .into_bytes();
            response.extend(encoded);
            match stream.write(&response) {
                Ok(_) => println!("Response sent"),
                Err(e) => println!("Failed sending response: {}", e),
            }
            stream.flush().unwrap();
            }
        ("POST", _) => {
            // handle the POST request
        }
        _ => {
            // handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea where that stack overflow suddenly comes from?
Note: The thread is created as is in the main:

```
let comm_thread = thread::spawn(|| {
            handle_communication();
        });
```

Also, bonus question : how can I easily get the file type in order to differentiate the header content-type? Thanks

Comment: running the binary with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run`/`RUST_BACKTRACE=1 ./house_status 1` will give more information about the error

Comment: I'm afraid it did not output anything more. On the other hand, I found out that the stack overflow occured at the ```let mut encoder = Encoder::with_chunks_size(&mut encoded, 8);
                encoder.write_all(&buf).unwrap(); ``` but I don't know why

Comment: Is there another loop somewhere that isn't terminating properly?

Comment: There is none, as when I'm querying an html page everything's fine, even with multiple queries

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**